# Android Handler problem

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here, but the following code:

```
...

public void onClick(View v) {
  extractThread et = new extractThread();
  et.start();
}

...

private class extractThread extends Thread{

  public void run(){
    expensiveOperation();

    Message m = new Message();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("message","result");
    m.setData(b);
    extractHandler.dispatchMessage(m);
    }
}

private Handler extractHandler = new Handler(){

  public void handleMessage(Message m){

    Bundle b = m.getData();
    String message = b.getString("message");

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(message)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
              }
    });
    builder.create().show();
  }
};
```

is still getting

```
01-07 11:55:02.791: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18791): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

at the line `builder.create().show();`, despite the fact this is called inside a Handler in my main thread inside `handleMessage`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the code you posted within your `Activity` class?

I would also use

```
Message msg = Message.obtain();
```

rather than creating a new message.  Also if you just want to pass a `String` then:

```
private static final int HANDLER_MESSAGE_RESULT = 0;
...
msg.what = HANDLER_MESSAGE_RESULT;
msg.obj = "result";
```

is more efficient than passing a `Bundle`.  In your `Handler` you can then `switch` on the `what` which allows you to add new message types in the future.  I think you should also be using:

```
extractHandler.sendMessage(m);
```

rather than

```
extractHandler.dispatchMessage(m);
```

Not sure that any of that fixes your issue though!

Comment: Thanks, very helpful advice, and it was the use of `dispatchMessage()` that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was something stupid. I should have used `extractHandler.sendMessage(m);` instead of `extractHandler.dispatchMessage(m);`